# Allow user to create and mange scheduled task on windows 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, task-scheduler

I have recently create a new user on a windows 2008 server and I want to allow it to open the task scheduler and manage the shceduled tasks. What right does this user need in order to achieve this?

Comment: To manage all tasks it should be a member of the Administrators group and have full control on the "%systemroot%\windows\tasks" folder

Comment: What if I want him to administer only task that he scheduled? I dont want to make him an admin member

Comment: Is this a standalone, member server or DC? Will the user be logging on remotely or locally?